# Angular observable behavior odd when shared

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an observable that when I use the rxjs 'share' operator behaves strangely in the Angular template. Here's how I setup my two observables (in a service):

```
this.family = this.store.select(getFamily).pipe(
  tap(family => {
    if (family == null) {
      this.loadFamily();
    }
  }),
  filter(family => family != null),
  share(),
);
this.familyMembers = this.family.pipe(
  map(family => {
    return family.familyMembers;
  })
);
```

I then add the familyMember observable to my component as a property

```
this.familyMembers = this.familyService.familyMembers
```

My markup looks something like this:

```
 <tbody *ngIf="(familyMembers | async) != null">
        <pre> {{(familyMembers | async) | json}}</pre>
```

Now the strange thing is when familyMembers is populated (an array of two), the `<pre>` will render with `null` inside even after i've checked for null with the `*ngIf`.

I also have a list that does not render anything as follows:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-familyMember let-i="index" [ngForOf]="(familyMembers | async)" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
```

I know that the last thing `familyMembers` observable emitted was the correct two family members, I've checked this with `map` and `console.log`. The Angular template seems to be seeing this as null.. but also not?

Everything works if I remove the `share()` from the family observable but the `tap()` runs twice which is not desirable.

**EDIT:**

Using shareReplay() instead of share() fixed my problem. share() will not re-emit values when all subscriptions unsubscribe.

Comment: try to <tbody *ngIf="familyMembers.length > 0 | async"> and then,  <pre> {{familyMembers | json}}</pre>

Comment: <tbody *ngIf="(familyMembers | async) != null && (familyMembers | async).length > 0"> resulted in an error: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: this is not what I've wrote, but try this again: <tbody *ngIf="familyMembers | async as familyProps"> and then, <pre> {{familyProps | json}}</pre> , pay attention to what I wrote, and try it without adding your addition, if it wont work ill try to figure something else

Comment: Your second suggestion worked and rendered the expected outcome - I don't understand why using the 'as' had any effect on it.

Comment: I added the answer, feel free to mark it if I helped you, good luck !

Comment: This is very similar a [question I just posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59109448/asyncpipe-initial-value-null-only-if-subscription-is-not-shared), with the exception that the answer here does not cover why using `shareReplay` fixes the problem of getting `null` (as the `null` is the default value that `AsyncPipe` returns if the given observable has no values at the time of template evaluation). Did you manage to explain this and care to enlighten me as I am slightly confused why `shareReplay` fixes the `null` issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the shared() operator since you are subscribe twice, that's why you got the duplicate.

You should change your html code accordingly :

```
 <tbody *ngIf="familyMembers | async as familyProps">
        <pre> {{familyProps | json}}</pre>
```

In the first *ngIf you check for the existence of the values, so there is no need to use async pipe again in the other row since it won't be called if its not passed the first one.

Plus, when you calling 'as familyProps' and using it in the next line, you are sure that this local object will be available when this line executes. It might work without the 'as', but from your comment, I just add it to make sure.

--EDIT

Each async pipe that you call will subscribe too, now what happen is that the first line with *ngIf waiting for the values, and the second line located inside this wrapper, so it won't call until the first line executes.

Now, when the first line pass, the second line will try to subscribe with the async pipe but its already completes, because of the first line subscription and the shared() operator.

You can try this, and it should work as well:

```
<tbody *ngIf="familyMembers | async">
  <pre> {{familyMembers | json}} </pre>
```

Comment: @that_guy , check the edit, I hope it helps to understand.

Comment: I see, so once all subscriptions to the family observable have unsubscribed, the observable completes and will not emit any more values?

Comment: If there will be more values its your decision and project dependent, but the issue is your second async pipe get called after the observable completes.

Comment: using shareReplay() fixed all my problems - thanks for the help